# Can you switch between octoling and inkling after the initial choice?

Tags: splatoon-3

Been playing an octoling and for variety, would like to switch to an inkling.

But I can't find the option in the menus.

Can you?

Comment: Currently I'm not at home so I can't check where exactly I've found this but I've changed to octoling from inkling (this is the right name btw) yesterday, IIRC it was option -> player setting or something like that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, you can.

From Options, choose "Player Settings":

[image]

Then you can change your species and gender:

[image]